# How to append items from a list into a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm very new to programming and Python and trying to figure things out. I'm trying to take items out of a list and append the keys and values to a dictionary but I can't figure out how. I tried using the dictionary's Update method but I'm only getting the last item from my list, not all the items. Here is my code:

```
a = {}
names = [ {'name': 'Bart'}, {'name': 'Lisa'}, {'name': 'Maggie'} ] 
for name in names:
     a.update(name)
```

The result I'm getting back is:

```
{'name': 'Maggie'}
```

But I want this in my new dictionary:

```
{'name': 'Bart'}, {'name': 'Lisa'}, {'name': 'Maggie'}
```

I wanted to put the items from the list inside the dictionary in order to access the values. I need all of the names but maybe there is a much easier way to do it.

Any hints would be great. Thanks.

Comment: What then would you want `a['name']` to result in? A dictionary can have only one value for a particular key. What it looks like you want is a list of dictionaries, ... which you already have.

Comment: thats not a dictionary...

Comment: Ok, so then how do I access the values inside of the list? For example, if I want to access the name "Bart" how would I do that?

Comment: I wanted to put the items from the list inside the dictionary in order to access the values. I need all of the names but maybe there is a much easier way to do it.

Comment: That list of dictionaries looks pretty useless. Is there more information that you're leaving out? For example, `{'name': 'Bart', 'age': 43}, {'name': 'Lisa', 'age': 27}` might result in a meaningful dictionary like `{'Bart': {'age': 43}, 'Lisa': {'age': 27}}`.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are expecting. Your example of what you want isn't a dictionary at all, it's a `tuple` of single-key `dict` objects, the key in all of them being `'name'`. It is equivalent to your original `names` `list` of `dict` objects. What, exactly are you looking for? Are you asking how to access a value corresponding to a key in a `dict`? Your `names` `list` doesn't make any sense. Why a bunch of single-key `dict` objects? Why not just *the names*? i.e. `names = ['Bart', 'Lisa', 'Maggie']`

Comment: I don't think you know what a dictionary is, nor what it is used for. Please revisit your question and come back when you have a clear problem statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With same key value you cant update a dict from list of dict. You can get a dict with key a list of values.

```
{'name': ['Bart', 'Lisa', 'Maggie']}

a={}
    for n in names:
    ...     for k in n:
    ...             for k,v in [(k,n[k])]:
    ...                     if k not in a:a[k]=[v]
    ...                     else: a[k].append(v)
```